# undefined local variable or method `admins_root_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a issue with my rails code, i try to create a new location based on the input.
So the create method looks like this:

```
  def create
    @location = Location.new(params[:location])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.save
        # format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Location was successfully created.' }
        format.html { redirect_to admins_root_path, notice: 'Location was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @location, status: :created, location: @location }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

It ends up with the following error output:

```
undefined local variable or method `admins_root_path' for #<LocationsController:0x007fa18917f278>
app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:47:in `block in create'
app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:45:in `create'
```

Any help would be very helpful.

Comment: Please post the output of `rake routes`

Comment: List your routes file plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`admins_root_path` doesn't have a defined route. The following will define a named match route for it:

```
match 'path/to/admin/root' => 'admins#root_action', :as => 'admins_root'
```

More than likely, however, you're simply invoking the wrong route. For instance, it's possible that you are trying to route to the `admins#index` action, in which case you'd do the following:

```
format.html { redirect_to admins_path, notice: 'Location was successfully created.' }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be with the route 'admins_root_path' that you're passing when the location is saved.  In the console if you type `rake routes` you will see a list of all routes available to you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's supposed to be `admin_root_path` or just `root_path` depending on how you configured your routes, but if you want to see all the routes available to you and make sure you are using one of them you should follow @lflores' suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have meet this problem, too.
I checked : routes.rb, there have a problem . I haven't write: resources. and I add the resources, solved the problem.

**my wrong code:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
  namespace :admin do

  end
  resources :jobs
  root 'jobs#index'
end
```

**my right code**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
  resources :jobs
  end
  resources :jobs
  root 'jobs#index'
end
```